# What is the cost function of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

```
input : arr[n]
output : median value of arr

for i = 0 ... n/2
  for j = 0 ... i
      if arr[j] > arr[n-i-1]
         temp = arr[j]
         arr[j] = arr[n-i-1]
         arr[n-i-1] = temp
```

I know the complexity of the algorithm is O(n^2). I could not find a specific definition of the cost function. Should I include comparisons in the loop and if statement as costs? It would be helpful if someone could define what a cost function is and help me understand and solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, comparisons must be included in cost.  There are about `n^2/8` comparisons that give quadratic complexity.

Note that you don't know real number of swaps but this fact does not influence on complexity. Number of operations varies from `n^2/8` to `4*n^2/8` but both expressions belong to `Theta(n^2)` class

Exact cost calculation depends on your book approach and instructor willings :).

In general one have to calculate all operators with cost 1 (despite of some ones might be internally complex like for-loop). For example, `for i = 0 ... n/2` gives cost `n/2`, both `for j = 0 ... i` and `if arr[j] > arr[n-i-1]` give cost `k=n/2*(n/2-1)/2`and swaps give cost in range `k..3k`

So overall cost is

```
n/2 + 2 * n/2*(n/2-1)/2 + x * n/2*(n/2-1)/2
```

where x depends on data and lies in range 1..3

Comment: Could you give a clear definition of cost function?

Comment: Moved comment into answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider number of comparison in both the `for` loops and `if` statement and number of times `for` loops runs